# computation of vectors from mean vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

a=[1,2,3,4] , b=[4,5,6,7] and c=[3,2,1,4] are vectors. Now d=mean of the vectors(a,b,c)=[2.66,3,3.33,5]. Is it possible to get a,b,c OR approximate a,b,c using d and any method

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first components only. As long as they satisfy the following

$x_1+x_2+x_3=3a_1$

they are eligible to make the first components of the vectors. Same is true for other components. There is an infinite number of possibilities, unless you put more contraints.

Comment: would you please give a small example regarding this

Comment: @c.rajakumar, just take the vectors that you have mentioned. Add x to the first component of vector a and subtract x from the first element of vector b. This way, they add to the same number as before. So, their mean is the same. Now, you can vary x, to get an infinite number of group of vectors that satisfy the condition.